# How can "allows nil" be added to a type declaration in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, types, ruby-3

I'm familiar with type annotations in Ruby. However, no where have found a mention about nilable types. That is, something similar to this:

```
class Merchant
  attr_reader token: String # never nil
  attr_reader name: String # how to signal it that it may be nil? 
  [.......]
end
```

And vise versa: I want to be able to describe a type which doesn't allow nil values.

Is that possible? How?

**update1:**

```
irb(main):009:0> tp1 = String
=> String
irb(main):010:0> v1 = "fdsafds"
=> "fdsafds"
irb(main):011:0> tp1 === v1
=> true
irb(main):012:0> tp2 = String?
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):12:in `<main>'
NoMethodError (undefined method `String?' for main:Object)
Did you mean?  String
```

Why does it fail?

Answer (score 2):

You can see an example of this right on the landing page of [RBS](https://github.com/ruby/rbs):

> ```ruby
> attr_reader reply_to: Message? # `?` means optional type: `#reply_to` can be `nil`
> ```

And more specifically, it is in [the *Syntax* documentation](https://github.com/ruby/rbs/blob/master/docs/syntax.md#optional-type):

> #### Optional type
>
> Optional type denotes *a type of value or nil*.
>
> ```ruby
> Integer?
> Array[Integer?]
> ```

So, for your case, that would be

```ruby
attr_reader name: String?
```